# Fitnesse Slim with C# getting slim protocol version error

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I'm a noob with Fitnesse/Slim.  I downloaded the latest fitnesse.jar and C# slim (v 1.8) and I'm getting the following error when attempting to follow along with the tutorial:

Slim Protocol Version Error
Expected V0.3 but was V0.1

Is there a way to specify what version of Slim I'm using?

edit: Slim:  release.1.8.net.40.zip - for .NET 4
      Fitnesse: v20110104

Any thoughts/direction would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fitSharp (C# Slim) is running behind the latest FitNesse Slim version.  It will catch up with the next release.  The error is really just a warning and your tests should run OK as long as they don't use any features from the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this tutorial ?
http://schuchert.wikispaces.com/FitNesse.Tutorials.0#Continue%20Tutorial%20in%20C#

The Java-Example is working correct.

The C#-Example doesn't test at all:
**EXCEPTION**:System.BadImageFormatException
Tested with SharpDevelop and VS C# 2010 Express.

Look at this: http://www.jowenmei.com/?p=691

> Note: I couldnt get the latest version of FitNesse working with the latest version 
>   of nslim (the plugin for .Net)… **I took a previous version of FitNesse.**